# Let the end user draw shapes on bing maps (Virtual Earth)

Tags: javascript, drawing, bing-maps

How to let the end user draw shapes at runtime on bing maps (Virtual Earth)?

Comment: Any particular shapes? Circles, ellipses, rectangles, squares, or just arbitrary polygons? Each shape has their own set of trouble spots implementation-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/index.cfm?fa=home). You could combine these two samples:

- [Add a Virtual Earth map layer](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/ve_layer.html)
- [Use a drawing toolbar](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html)